# Do we want to participate in this year's Hat Dash?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

Last year, [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) had a little promotion around the holidays called the [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), wherein meeting certain activity thresholds would earn hats that a user's avatar could then "wear" throughout the site:

[image: Hats from last year]

This year, Stack Exchange has decided to open up the Hat Dash to any site that decides to opt-in. The specifics:

> This event will run from **19 December 2012** to **4 January 2013**. Users
>   will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh.
>   That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and
>   other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option
>   available, just as we had on Gaming last year.
>
> The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the
>   hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to respond by **November 28th** if the site would like to participate. Any site that does not respond by that date is considered to be opted-out.

So, what say you, people of A.SE? Should we participate in the Hat Dash this year, or would we prefer to opt-out of it entirely?

---

We have **opted in** to this promotion, so prepare for the arrival of hats this December!

Comment: I'm fine with it.... they need an Android hat :)

Comment: Hats are the most awesome!

Comment: Yes. I'm up for almost anything that will promote the site and encourage greater participation.

Comment: Yes please!  HatDash was awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, why not.

There's no reason why we shouldn't opt-in. [If Android likes to be cool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.androidify), why its Enthusiasts can't. Go for it without turning back...